# Issue with JTextPane and regex

Tags: java, regex, counter, jtextpane, styleddocument

I have a `JTextPane` which contains a string of XML characters, and I wish to change the colour of XML opening tags; to do this I use a regex to find the opening tags, then set the character attribute of the relevant text indexes to the chosen color. This can be seen in the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class Test {
    String nLine = java.lang.System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
    String xmlString = "<ROOT>" + nLine + "  <TAG>Tag Content</TAG>" + nLine + "  <TAG>Tag Content</TAG>" + nLine + "  <TAG>Tag Content</TAG>" + nLine + "</ROOT>";

    public Test(){
        JTextPane XMLTextPane = new XMLTextPane();
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(XMLTextPane);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,100));
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, pane);
    }

    class XMLTextPane extends JTextPane{
        public XMLTextPane(){
            super.setText(xmlString);
            StyleContext context = new StyleContext();
            Style openTagStyle = context.addStyle("Open Tag", null);
            openTagStyle.addAttribute(StyleConstants.Foreground, Color.BLUE);
            StyledDocument sdocument = this.getStyledDocument();

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([a-z]|[A-Z])+");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(super.getText());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                sdocument.setCharacterAttributes(matcher.start(), matcher.group().length() , openTagStyle, true);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

The problem however is that `Matcher.start()` and `StyledDocument.setCharacterAttributes()` appear to increment differently (It seems as though `StyledDocument` ignores newline characters), thus causing the coloured text to stagger.

[image]

The issue is not with the regex itself, as a `System.out.println(matcher.group());` in the while loop reveals the following correct output:

```
<ROOT
<TAG
<TAG
<TAG
```

Is there a way to force `Matcher.start()` and `StyledDocument.setCharacterAttributes()` to increment consistently, or will I have to implement a new line counter?

EDIT: As Schlagi suggested, replacing all `\r\n` with `\n` **does** work, however I worry that this makes the code a little confusing and difficult to maintain. Other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why the JTextPane do it wrong. It could be, that in the styledocument think, that `"\r\n"` is only one character. Do not asked why.

When you change the line

```
String nLine = java.lang.System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

to

```
String nLine = "\n";
```

it works.
JTextPane only need a `"\n"` for a newline on every OS

Comment: Unfortunately in the actual application the input xml uses \r\n as a line seperater so this will not work.

Comment: A workaround is to replace all `"\r\n"` with `"\n"`.

Comment: @btrs20 Take a look at [DefaultEditorKit Newlines (Java Platform SE 8)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html)

Comment: @schlagi123 replacing all \r\n does work, although I can't help feeling it's a little 'scrappy'. Will wait a bit to see if anyone else has any better suggestions and accept your answer if not.